# Could a laptop fingerprint sensor be used as a webcam?

Tags: privacy, chromebook

I have a Chromebook that normally only recognizes the actual webcam. However, I opened up a random webcam site and it was allowing me to use a second camera for some reason. When I enabled it, I realized that it was using the little fingerprint sensor that sits next to the keyboard. The displayed image was of my ceiling.

Is this normal? I would have thought that would be a privacy concern considering it doesn't come with a shutter like the actual camera.

Can all laptop fingerprint sensors be also used as a camera?

Comment: *"Can all laptop sensors be also used as a camera ?."* - are you really asking if thermal sensors, touch sensors (touch pad), microphones ... can also be used as a camera? This does not make sense for me because of how these are physically built.

Comment: If it is a camera, then it can be used as a camera. If it is not, then it cannot. Either you are confused about what you saw on the screen, or the fingerprint sensor is in fact a camera. Check with the laptop's documentation to determine if it is a camera.